# Append ' before and after char[] in C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, string-concatenation, strcat

I am trying to append single quotes before and after a char array. Following is the code I am trying:

```
static const char str[] = "select * from name";
STATICF boolean test(){
   char[] key = "1234";
   strcat(str,(const char *)"\'");
   strcat(str,key);
   strcat(str,(const char *)"\'");
}
```

It does not work as I get segmentation fault. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strcat(str,(const char *)"\'");
strcat(str,key);
strcat(str,(const char *)"\'");
```

`str` needs to be big enough to hold the whole concatenated result string, plus `\0` to terminate the string. This isn´t the case at your example with the declaration of `str` as:

```
static const char str[] = "select * from name";
```

with `str` to hold only the size of the old string plus `\0`. Thus, trying to append more characters causes the segmentation fault.

---

Try to declare `str` with a fixed size, large enough to hold the result string (the old string of `select * from name` + `\'` + `1234` + `\'` + the terminating `\0` which shall be 25 characters in total if I´d counted right).

`str` needs to be non-constant to change the value of `str` by the way, so omit `static const`.

Also omit the cast of `(const char *)`; and replace `"\'"` with `"'"`.

The result is like the following:

```
char str[25];
strcpy(str,"select * from name");
STATICF boolean test(){
   char key[] = "1234";
   strcat(str,"'");
   strcat(str,key);
   strcat(str,"'");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The array `str` is initialized to be exactly as big as the string that initializes it.  This means that attempting to append anything to that string will write past the end of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case causes your program to crash.

You need to make the destination string big enough to hold the resulting string, and you need to not qualify it as `const`.

Also, manually constructing a SQL string is a bad idea as it can lead to a SQL injection attack.  You should instead use prepared statements which can inject parameters into a command safely.

```
static const char str[] = "select * from name";
STATICF boolean test(){
   char[] key = "1234";
   int len = strlen(str) + 1 + strlen(key) + 1 + 1;
   char dest[len];
   strcpy(dest,str);
   strcat(dest,"'");
   strcat(dest,key);
   strcat(dest,"'");
}
```

Comment: The problem is not appending. Just writing to *any position* of a `const char []` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, doing `strcpy()` + `strcat()` 3 times iterates over the whole string a total of 4 times, which is not really needed.